# Find the distribution of a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, lebesgue-measure

Let $\Omega=[0,1]$, $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{B} \cap [0,1]$, and $P$ be the Lebesgue measure restricted to $[0,1]$. Let $\Phi_{\mu,\sigma^2}(x)=\mathcal{N}_{\mu,\sigma^2}((-\infty,x]) $. Then it is clear that $\xi=\Phi^{-1}_{\mu,1}$ is a random variable on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$.
Can anyone show me how to find the distribution of $\xi$ under $P$ ? and also $\Bbb{E}(\eta)=1$ under $P$, where $\eta=e^{-\mu\xi+\mu^2/2}$.

Comment: It is better to write something $\mathcal{F} = \left\{ B
\cap \left[ 0, 1 \right] : B \in \mathcal{B} \right\}$ while mentioning that
$\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel sigma field. $\mathcal{B} \cap \left[ 0, 1 \right]$
is not good notation.

Comment: These notations are given by my lecturer.

Answer (score 2):

The distribution of $\xi$ under $P$ is $\Phi_{\mu, 1}$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
  P \left\{ \omega : \xi \left( \omega \right) \leqslant x \right\} & = & P
  \left\{ \omega : \Phi^{- 1}_{\mu, 1} \left( \omega \right) \leqslant x
  \right\}\\
  & = & P \left\{ \omega : \omega \leqslant \Phi_{\mu, 1} \left( x \right)
  \right\}\\
  & = & \Phi_{\mu, 1} \left( x \right)
\end{eqnarray*}
The second line follows by strict monotonicity and the third by the properties
of Lebesgue measure on $\left[ 0, 1 \right]$ (uniform distribution).
Then that distribution has probability density function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm{e}^{- \frac{x^2}{2}}$, resulting in
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{- \mu x + \frac{\mu^2}{2}}
  \mathrm{e}^{- \frac{x^2}{2}} \mathrm{d} x & = & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{- \infty}^{\infty}
  \mathrm{e}^{- \frac{\left( x - \mu \right)^2}{2}} \mathrm{d} x\\
  & = & 1
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: How to show the expectation of $\eta$?

Comment: This is a simple calculus question. You know the distribution now, so compute the integral.

Comment: It's not simple to me. Can u please show me? thanks

Comment: The definition of probability distribution of $\xi$ given by my lecture is $F(x)=(P\circ\xi^{-1})((-\infty,x])$. I can't link the definition with your answer. Can u please further in terms of the definition? Thanks

Comment: I mean explain further